# docker run --entrypoint "python /path/to/file.py" cause "no such file or directory: unknown." error

Tags: docker

Running `docker run  -it --entrypoint "bash" fnb-backend` and then `python /app/main/src/api/frontend/customer_api/customer_api.py` in container shell works fine.

Consider Dockerfile below:

```
FROM python:2.7.18-slim
COPY main/requirements.txt .
RUN cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install --no-cache-dir; exit 0
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
COPY . ./app/
RUN mkdir -p /app/main/logs/flask/ && touch /app/main/logs/flask/webhook_api.log
# below works
#ENTRYPOINT python /app/main/src/api/frontend/customer_api/customer_api.py
```

The commented out line works fine too.

However running `docker run --entrypoint "python /app/main/src/api/frontend/customer_api/customer_api.py" fnb-backend` cause:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "python /app/main/src/api/frontend/customer_api/customer_api.py": stat python /app/main/src/api/frontend/customer_api/customer_api.py: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Comment: (What happens if you run that entrypoint command locally, including the double quotes?  Why?)

Answer (score 0):

- What you used in Dockerfile is shell form of `ENTRYPOINT`, see [next](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2

- What you used in docker run using `--entrypoint` could override the command of `ENTRYPOINT` in `Dockerfile`, this means it can just act as `command`, not the syntax of `command param1 param2`, see [next](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime):

> Passing --entrypoint will clear out any default command set on the image

In fact, for `--entrypoint`, docker will treat it as a whole command, so if you use `command param1 param2`, it will try to find the executable of `command param1 param2`, it will result `file not found`.

For you, the correct way is next which put `params` to command of `docker run`:

```
docker run --entrypoint python fnb-backend /app/main/src/api/frontend/customer_api/customer_api.py
```